# Rest api design for an API which can consume three different type of json request

Tags: java, json, spring-boot, rest, file-upload

I have a input field or you can assume its a question, for which the user interaction can be of 3 types.

1. Text
2. Selection (multichoice)
3. Image upload (multiple medias)

I want to understand what should be the standard way to accept these responses.

I was thinking to have an API and request like below for Selection

**[http://example.com/input/{id}/response](http://example.com/input/%7Bid%7D/response)**

```
Request Sample
{
   "selections": [id1, id2]
}
```

for text type

**[http://example.com/input/{id}/response](http://example.com/input/%7Bid%7D/response)**

```
Request Sample
{
   "inputValue": "some input provided"
}
```

for media type

**[http://example.com/input/{id}/response](http://example.com/input/%7Bid%7D/response)**

```
Request Sample
{
   "files": [
      {"name":"medianame", "type":"mediaType"}
    ]
}
```

But then if user wants to add a new file to the existing response, there need to be another API

**[http://example.com/input/{id}/response/{responseId}/upload](http://example.com/input/%7Bid%7D/response/%7BresponseId%7D/upload)**

This doesn't seem right and readable, what could be the possible best design solution ?

Comment: @Kayaman I think for the below reasons
1) There is just 1 API consuming 3 different request and there is no consistency, the use case here forces it to do so, but I belive it can be handled in a better way.

2) This will need better file upload APIs considering the file size, passing a list of files(maybe some kind of presigned s3 urls)

3) If there is a different type in future, say boolean or numeric values. Then there are going to be more dyanmic response types to be handled at server side.

So far I have these things in mind, but there can be more.

Comment: More response types means modifications on both client and server in any case. If the same endpoint can handle all responses, then there is in fact consistency, since the client doesn't need to guess which endpoint to use, and the server code should remain simple using some traditional design pattern in the style of [COR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chain-of-responsibility_pattern). Based on the information *shown* I don't see anything particularly bad here, but your file upload case doesn't seem to be fully thought out yet, so that may change things.

Comment: @Kayaman I found your insight helpful. Any thoughts on file upload side ? how can I make it better ?

Comment: Is your current plan to first provide the names and types with one call, then data with the other? In any case since the file upload will be more complex than any text form answer, it will probably need its own separate handling mechanism. Although you might want to combine the name, type and data input into a single call (the name/type in request parameters and data in body) and just send multiple files one after another. That would at least give you "simple" and "complex" endpoint.

Comment: Understood this definitely might need a separte endpoint, yep I have considered the data along with the name and type.